# How to config AspectJ in Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I want to use .aj files in my android project, It works fine in Eclipse. But how to make it work in Android Studio?
I tried the Aspectj weaver plugin but it seems cannot apply the aspects to the project.

Comment: I searched google for a while and found the AspectJ plugin for IntelliJ is available in Ultimate edition. Will Android Studio add AspectJ support in future?